# Simple todolist Bradtraversy lower limit error

Tags: python, django, linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to run the [bradtraversy simple todo list](https://github.com/bradtraversy/django-todolist) django code on my raspberry pi and have run into the following error. I have run into the following traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: HIDDEN

Django Version: 1.11.11
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
['todos.apps.TodosConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  138.             response = self.process_request(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  57.         host = request.get_host()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py" in get_host
  105.         if domain and validate_host(domain, allowed_hosts):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py" in validate_host
  579.         if pattern == '*' or is_same_domain(host, pattern):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/http.py" in is_same_domain
  291.     pattern = pattern.lower()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I am fairly new to Django but thought I made all the correct adjustments to match my system specifics. I updated the settings file to match my allowed hosts and database setting and used the "python manage.py migrate" command to bring over migrations.

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting appears to be invalid - show us what that is.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke, I took a closer look at my allowed host and found a typographical error. I fixed a minor url items and got this up and running now. Thank you!